# Peculiar (convergent?) definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

I have been trying to calculate the integral:

$$\int_1^{\infty} \left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4-1}}-1\right)dx$$

A hint is to multiply the whole integral by $x^{\lambda}$, calculate the two terms independently as a function of $\lambda$ and then set $\lambda=0$. But this did not work.

By substituting $x=\frac{1}{u}$ the integral transforms into $$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}-1\right)\frac{1}{u^2}du$$

which leads to a Beta function with one negative argument.

The result should be $$1-\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^2}$$

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo mistake. But this integral does not seem to give a finite result anyway. The first term will lead to the Beta function with the negative argument and the other one will give infinite.

Comment: The integral is convergent, because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}=1+\frac{u^4}{2}+o(u^4)$ around $0$.

Answer (score 4):

The integral in $u\in[0,1]$ is for me simpler, so let us introduce for a handy notation
$$y=y(u) = \sqrt{1-u^4}\ .
$$
Then for the integral to be calculated we observe first
$$
\frac\partial{\partial u}
\left(\frac{1-y}u\right) = 
\frac{u^2}y-\left(\frac 1y-1\right)\frac 1{u^2}\ .
$$
So we need to calculate
$$
\begin{aligned}
J
&=
\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}-1\right)\frac{1}{u^2}\;du
%\\&
=
\int_0^1 \left(\frac1y-1\right)\frac{1}{u^2}\;du
\\
&=\left[\frac {1-y}u\right]_0^1
-
\int_0^1 \frac{u^2}y\;du
%\\&
=
1
-
\int_0^1 \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}\;du
\\
&= 1-\frac 14B\left(\frac 12,\frac 34\right)\qquad
\text{ with $B$ being the $\beta$-function}
\\
&=1-\frac 14\cdot\frac  
{\Gamma\left(\frac 12\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac 34\right)}
{\Gamma\left(\frac 54\right)}
%\\&
=1-\frac 14\cdot\frac  
{\sqrt\pi\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac 34\right)}
{\frac 14\Gamma\left(\frac 14\right)}
\\
&=1-\sqrt\pi
\cdot
\frac  
{\Gamma\left(\frac 14\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac 34\right)}
{\Gamma\left(\frac 14\right)^2}
%\\&
=1-\sqrt\pi
\cdot
\frac  
{\sqrt{2\pi}\Gamma\left(2\cdot\frac 14\right)}
{\Gamma\left(\frac 14\right)^2}
\\
&
=
1-
\frac 12
(2\pi)^{3/2}\cdot 
\frac  
1{\Gamma\left(\frac 14\right)^2}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
I tried to represent the result closer to the shape of the prediction in the OP.

---

We have the assisted checks / numerical validations:

```
sage: value = 1 - (2*pi)^(3/2) / 2 / gamma(1/4)^2
sage: value.n()
0.400929882632204
sage: var('u');
sage: integral( (1/sqrt(1-u^4) - 1)/u^2, u, 0, 1).n()
0.40092987307719175
sage: integral( u^2/sqrt(1-u^4), u, 0, 1)
1/4*beta(1/2, 3/4)
```

Comment: How the hell did you come with that differential identity ? I like the solution eh ... where you driven just by the fact that you knew that you could integrate stuff like $\int_0^1  u^a/y \ du $ via the beta function approach ? Or which was your approach ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$ \int_0^1x^{p-1}(1-x)^{q-1}dx=\frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(q)}{\Gamma(p+q)}, \Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$$
Under $u=t^{1/4},t=\sin ^{2}v$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}-1\right)\frac{1}{u^2}du\\
&=&\frac14\int_0^{1}\bigg(-t^{-5/4}+t^{-5/4}(1-t)^{-1/2}\bigg)dt.
\end{eqnarray}
Noting that
$$ \int_0^1\left(-t^{-a}+t^{-a}(1-t)^{-1/2}\right)dt=\int_0^1\frac{1}{t^{a-1}(1-t)^{1/2}\left(1+(1-t)^{1/2}\right)}dt$$
converges for $a<2$, so one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}-1\right)\frac{1}{u^2}du\\
&=&\lim_{a\to\frac54}\frac14\int_0^{1}\bigg(-t^{-a}+t^{-a}(1-t)^{-1/2}\bigg)dt\\
&=&\lim_{a\to\frac54}\frac14\left(\frac{1}{a-1}+\frac{\Gamma(1-a)\Gamma(\frac12)}{\Gamma(\frac32-a)}\right)\\
&=&1+\frac{\sqrt\pi\Gamma(-\frac14)}{\Gamma(\frac14)}\\
&=&1-\frac{\sqrt2\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma^2(\frac14)}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: How do you justify the transition from integral to gammas? Of course, it can be done using analytic continuation, but I'm in doubt it's supposed to be done by OP...

Comment: @xpaul Indeed, any comment on the analytical continuation? I am not an expert and I would be curious to know what needs to be checked to make that step formal...

Comment: @metamorphy, see the update

Comment: @Thomas, see the update